# Detectar click en repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estoy realizando un menú con C# y Jquery utilizando el control Repeater en asp.net, me estoy guiando de  este ejemplo: https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/108804/Database-Driven-N-Level-MultiLevel-BootstrapResponsive-Vertical-Menu-using-C-and-jQuery-in-ASPNet/lo estoy adaptando a lo que necesito, el menu se carga desde la base de datos.

**MasterPage**

```
 <div class="nav-side-menu">
        <div class="brand">
            Menú
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
        <div class="menu-list" style="width: 299px">
            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCategories" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptCategories_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptMenu_OnItemBound" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="button" runat="server" CommandName="captureItem" >  
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#<%#Eval("MenuName") %>' class="collapsed" >
                        <a
                            href='<%#Eval("Url") %>'>
                        <i class='<%#Eval("CssFont") %>'></i>
                                 <%#Eval("MenuName") %>                                     
                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltrlSubMenu" runat="server" > </asp:Literal>             
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**MasterPage.cs**

```
void rptCategories_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "captureItem")
        {

        }
    }
```

Lo que estoy buscando es que al hacer click en algún item del menú se dispare el evento ItemCommand y realice alguna acción pero no logro que suceda.

**Evento OnItemDataBound**

```
    protected void rptMenu_OnItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                if (Menus != null)
                {
                    DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
                    string MenuID = rowView["MenuID"].ToString();
                    string nombre = rowView["MenuName"].ToString();
                    DataRow[] rows = Menus.Select("ParentID= " + MenuID);
                    if (rows.Length > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append("<ul id='" + nombre + "' class='sub-menu collapse'>");
                        foreach (var item in rows)
                        {
                            string parentID = item["MenuID"].ToString();
                            string parentNombre = item["MenuName"].ToString();
                            //string idCarga = item["Upload_id"].ToString();
                            //Session["SP_ID"] = idCarga.ToString();

                            DataRow[] parentRows = Menus.Select("ParentID=" + parentID);
                            if (parentRows.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<li data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#" + parentNombre + "' class='collapsed'><a href='" + item["Url"] + "'>" + item["MenuName"] + "<span class='arrow'></span></a>");
                                sb.Append("</li>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("<li><a href='" + item["Url"] + "'>" + item["MenuName"] + "</a>");
                                sb.Append("</li>");
                            }
                            sb = CreateChild(sb, parentID, parentNombre, parentRows);

                        }
                        sb.Append("</ul>");
                        (e.Item.FindControl("ltrlSubMenu") as Literal).Text = sb.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Función para cargar datos al control asp repeater**

```
    private void llenarMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            Menus = GetData("SELECT MenuID,ParentID,Upload_id,MenuName,MenuOrder,Active,Url,CssFont FROM MenuWEB_Prueba WHERE active=1 ORDER BY MenuOrder");
            DataView view = new DataView(Menus);
            view.RowFilter = "ParentID=0";
            rptCategories.DataSource = view;
            rptCategories.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging(ex);
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging(ex);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Y en el pageLoad llamo la función llenarMenu

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            llenarMenu();
        }
    }
```

**Imagen de ejemplo**

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Comment: Agrego imagen de la vista del menú   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Of2albpukOGeNBlXICXuLrkxU0AKTFw7

Comment: en que evento estas cargando los datos del repeater ?

Comment: Hola Leandro, con el evento OnItemDataBound no sé quieres que agregue todo el código pero no se sí se vea bien.

Comment: el OnItemDataBound  es un evento que se ejecuta por cada item que se genera, pero alli no asignas el DataSource

Comment: Gracias. Entonces cual sería la manera correcta de asignar el Datasource? es que lo que busco es que al hacer Click en un item del repeater me traiga un dato de la tabla de donde se esta cargando los datos al repeater.

Comment: Leandro edite la publicación y agregue el código que estoy usando en el evento OnItemDataBound para que tengas un idea más clara de lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Como asignas los datos al repeater ?

Comment: Leandro nuevamente edite la publicación y agregue el código con el cual cargo los datos al repeater, que es la función llenarMenu y luego la llamo en el PageLoad con un Postback.